# Woocommerce Product Attributes Not Setting

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, attributes

I'm having a hard time getting the attributes setting. I have a function that creates the attributes if the attribute doesn't exist, and then applies it to the product. I just can't seem to get past this.

WC_Product_Attribute Object
(
[data:protected] => Array
(
[id] => 0
[name] => pa_upc
[options] => Array
(
[0] => 887
)

```
        [position] => 0
        [visible] => 1
        [variation] => 
    )
```

)

```
// Create a new WC_Product_Attribute object and set its properties
                $attr = new WC_Product_Attribute();
                $attr->set_name('pa_upc');
                $attr->set_options(array(887));
                $attr->set_visible(1); // Always visible
                $attr->set_variation(false);
                //$attr->set_position(0);
                $attr->set_id($attr_id);

                // Add the attribute to the $attrs array
                $attrs[] = $attr;
            }
            
            if (!empty($attrs)) {
                $product->set_attributes($attrs);
                $product->save();
                return true;
            }
```

```
public function set_attributes_from_array($post_id, $attributes_array) {
            $product = wc_get_product($post_id);
            if (!$product) {
                return false; // Product not found
            }

            $attrs = array(); // Initialize the attributes array outside the loop

            foreach ($attributes_array as $attribute_key => $attribute_value) {
                if (empty($attribute_value)) {
                    continue; // Skip if value is empty
                }

                $attribute_name = str_replace('attribute_pa_', '', $attribute_key);
                $taxonomy_name = $this->prepare_product_taxonomy_name($attribute_name);
                if (!taxonomy_exists($taxonomy_name)) {
                    continue; // Skip if taxonomy does not exist
                }

                $term_info = term_exists($attribute_value, $taxonomy_name) ?: wp_insert_term($attribute_value, $taxonomy_name);
                if (is_wp_error($term_info)) {
                    continue; // Skip if error in term creation
                }

                $term_id = isset($term_info['term_id']) ? $term_info['term_id'] : $term_info;

                $is_variation = ($product->get_type() === 'variable' && in_array($taxonomy_name, array_keys($product->get_variation_attributes()))) ? true : false;

                // Check if this attribute already exists in the product
                $existing_attrs = $product->get_attributes();
                $attr_id = 0; // Default to 0 (no term found)
                if (isset($existing_attrs[$taxonomy_name])) {
                    // Get the term slug or name from the attribute
                    $term_slug_or_name = $existing_attrs[$taxonomy_name];

                    // Get term by its 'slug' or 'name'
                    $term = get_term_by('slug', $term_slug_or_name, $taxonomy_name);
                    if (!$term) {
                        $term = get_term_by('name', $term_slug_or_name, $taxonomy_name);
                    }

                    // If the term exists, set $attr_id to the term's ID
                    if ($term && !is_wp_error($term)) {
                        $attr_id = $term->term_id;
                    }
                }

                // Create a new WC_Product_Attribute object and set its properties
                $attr = new WC_Product_Attribute();
                $attr->set_name($taxonomy_name);
                $attr->set_options(array($term_id));
                $attr->set_visible(1); // Always visible
                $attr->set_variation($is_variation);
                //$attr->set_position(0);
                $attr->set_id($attr_id);

                // Add the attribute to the $attrs array
                $attrs[] = $attr;
            }
            
            if (!empty($attrs)) {
                $product->set_attributes($attrs);
                $product->save();
                return true;
            }

            return false;
        }
```

I've tried switching around some of the variables, I've tried setting the array names to the taxonomy id, and a handful of other things. Im kind of stuck here.